# Example Compact Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a \in c_0(\mathbb{N})=\{a =(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N}) | lim ~a_n =0\}$ and $T_a: l^{p}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow l^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$ be defined by $T_a(x)=(a_kx_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ for $x \in l^{p}(\mathbb{N})$.

Put $(a_k^n)=a_k$ for $k=1, \dotsc, n$ and $0$ for $k \geq n+1$ and get that $\Vert a- a^n \Vert_{l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})}$ goes to $0$ as $a \in c_0(\mathbb{N})$.

Now $$
\Vert T_{a^n}-T_a \Vert _{ \mathcal{L}(l^{p}(\mathbb{N})} \leq \Vert a- a^n \Vert_{l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})}.$$

Why does this last inequality hold? (where $\Vert .\Vert _{ \mathcal{L}(l^{p}(\mathbb{N})}$ is the operator norm for linear and bounded operators, ie $\Vert T \Vert _{ \mathcal{L}(X)}= sup_{x \in X, \Vert x\Vert_X=1} \Vert Tx\Vert_X$).
Apparently it holds, as we then can show that $T_a$ is compact.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inequality holds only for $n \to \infty$, because, for example, let $a = (2,2,0,0,...), p=2$, then $||T_a - T_{a^1}||_{\mathcal{L}(\ell^{2})}=2^p=2^2=4$ but $||a-a^1||_{\ell^\infty}=2$.

To proof it you need inequality $|x|^p \leqslant |x|$ which holds for $|x| \leqslant 1, p \geqslant 1$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}$). And you can use it if you take $n$ large enough to get $||a^n - a||_{\ell^\infty} \leqslant 1$ (such $n$ exists because $a \in c_0$). Then you can get

$$||T_{a^n} - T_a||_{\mathcal{L}(\ell^{p})} = \sup_{||x||_{\ell^p} \leqslant 1} ||(T_{a^n} - T_a)(x)||_{\ell^p}= \sup_{||x||_{\ell^p} \leqslant 1} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |a_k|^p|x_k|^p \leqslant $$
$$\leqslant \sup_{||x||_{\ell^p} \leqslant 1} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (\sup_{k \in [n+1..\infty)} |a_k|^p)|x_k|^p  \leqslant$$

and for sufficiently large $n$ you can get $|a_k|^p \leqslant |a_k|$ thats why

$$\leqslant \sup_{||x||_{\ell^p} \leqslant 1} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (\sup_{k \in [n+1..\infty)} |a_k|)|x_k|^p = ||a-a^n||_{\ell^\infty} \sup_{||x||_{\ell^p} \leqslant 1} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |x_k|^p = ||a - a^n||_{\ell^\infty} \cdot 1$$